# Error while migrate grails-2.3.2 to 2.4.0 and JDK 1.7 to 1.8

Tags: grails, migration

I am migrating grails-2.4.0 from 2.3.2 and jdk-1.8 from 1.7.

I am using [this](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.3/guide/upgradingFrom23.html) article for migration.

**BuildConfig.groovy**

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        runtime 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.0.RELEASE'
    }

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"

    // Default plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.0"
    compile ':cache:1.1.3'

    // Persistency plugins
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.14"

    // Styling plugins
    runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:3.3.4'
    runtime ":resources:1.2.14"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.0.2"

    // PDF rendering plugins
    compile ":rendering:1.0.0"

    // Spring security plugins
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
    runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
    compile ":cache-headers:1.1.7"
}
```

Removed `grailsResourceLoader` from **applicationContext.xml**
Removed sitemesh filter details from **web.xml**

When I run the application using grails run-app it is working fine. But when I use update,Sort etc at that time below errors are occur.

Stacktrace

```
ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /wba-web/airline/index - parameters:
mode: 
modeId: 
Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <sitemesh:captureContent>: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:189)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <sitemesh:captureContent>: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
    at airline_index$_run_closure10.doCall(index:26)
    at airline_index.run(index:57)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
    at airline_index$_run_closure10_closure16.doCall(index:25)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at grails.util.CacheEntry.getValue(CacheEntry.java:141)
    at grails.util.CacheEntry.getValue(CacheEntry.java:81)
    ... 11 more
```

Does I miss something to upgrade? or this is bug in my code?

Quick help will highly appreciate.!!!

Please find log here [log.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5c_3cLHKaLvcGVBM2NqcTNjS3c/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was the error regarding filter. Every time filter block my request. I made some changes in my custom filter and it works.!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stacktrace the error is you are passing **null** value to the **render** function, when you are hitting **/wba-web/airline/index**. please copy the full stacktrace for more information.

Comment: This is full stacktrace. Do you need log?

Comment: Added log to the question.

Comment: can you show me the code. if not then try to print the value that you are rendering in the logs.It should not be null.

Comment: The same code was working fine for grails-2.3.2 so I don't think this is code issue.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Java have issues with Grails. However 1.8.0_25, 1.8.0_31 versions support 2.4.0. Those above 1.8.0_40 might have issues.

Comment: Which version of grails should recommend for Jdk-1.8.0_45?

Comment: Grails 3.0 above minimum requires Java 7. So try Grails 3.0+. If still you have issue, downgrade to Java 7.